# The difference between an Amazon S3 Get Request and an S3 Data retrieval

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

A theoretical question about Amazon S3.

There is a difference in pricing for an S3-IA Get Request:  $.001 / 10K
and an S3 data retrieval cost: $.01.

My question is, what is the difference between a Get Request and a Data Retrieval?

Answer (score 6):

In reference to the [Amazon S3 pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/):

- A **GET Request** is the act of *requesting* a file retrieval
- **Data Retrieval** is charged *per GB*, based on the size of the data being retrieved

In general, if you access something once per month or less often, then **Standard-Infrequent Access** is lower cost.

Answer (score 1):

From AWS documentation [AWS S3 Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/), it is mentioned as
`When you use the Amazon S3 console to browse your storage, you incur charges for GET, LIST, and other requests that are made to facilitate browsing. Charges are accrued at the same rate as requests that are made using the API/SDK`.
Which means a GET request not always need to be a data/file retrieval. It could be querying of some meta information as well.